# Typescript create Extensible nested types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an interface called Actions, which contains a property called Options, which would be different for different actions.

In the type definition:

```
export interface Action{
  id?: string;
  type: string;
  options: DrilldownOptions | SidepanelOptions;
}

export interface ActionOptions {
  name: string;
  icon?: any;
  source?: string;
}

export interface DrilldownOptions extends ActionOptions{
  page: string;
}

export interface SidepanelOptions extends ActionOptions{
  widget: any
}
```

Now I'm trying to access these in my execution method for each action.

So executor for drilldown action would be using

```
execute(action){
 const page = action.options.page
}
```

and this would result in error.

> property page doesn't exist on SidepanelOptions

Is there a better way of achieving this type of generic typing?

Comment: Consider editing the code into a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You say "when I try to use any property", but it would help to show what you mean by "use", with code. In any case your issue is likely to be that if you have an expression of a union type `A | B`, you can only safely access a property if both `A` and `B` have a property with that key. If you need to access a property in `A` but not in `B`, then you first must establish that you do have an `A`, via some [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Comment: @jcalz Sorry for the oversight, I added an example code. I see the approach using type-guards, but do you think there is a better way of doing what I'm trying to acheive? Could I create the interface in a more generic way perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a variable `action` of type `Action`, then as you have discovered, it is not safe to access `action.options.page` directly:

```
action.options.page; // error!   Property 'page' does not exist on type 'SidepanelOptions'.
```

That's because `action.options` is a union type and the `page` property is not known to exist on at least one member of the union.  To safely access `page`, you must use some sort of [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to narrow the type of `action.options` from `DrilldownOptions | SidepanelOptions` to just `DrilldownOptions`.

For example, since TypeScript 2.7, you can [use the `in` operator as a type guard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-guards-inferred-from--in-operator):

```
if ("page" in action.options) {
  action.options.page.charAt(0); // okay
} else {
  action.options.widget; // okay
}
```

Inside the "then" clause, `action.options` has been narrowed to `DrillDownOptions`, and inside the `else` clause, `action.options` has been narrowed to `SidepanelOptions`.

If you want to set a variable `page` to be `action.options.page` if it exists and `undefined` otherwise, you can use the `in` typeguard and a ternary operator like this:

```
const page = "page" in action.options ? action.options.page : undefined;
// const page: string | undefined
```

---

Another possible way to proceed is to define a wider options type, like this:

```
interface SomeOptions extends ActionOptions {
  page?: string;
  widget?: any;
}
```

Both `DrilldownOptions` and `SidepanelOptions` are assignable to `SomeOptions`, but not  vice versa.  Then, you can have a wider `Action` interface:

```
interface ActionWider {
  id?: string;
  type: string;
  options: SomeOptions;
}
```

And therefore an `Action` is assignable to `ActionWider`.  If it meets your needs you can just use `ActionWider` in place of your `Action`.  If not, you can safely widen `action` like this:

```
const widerAction: ActionWider = action; // okay
```

And then index into it without warning:

```
const page2 = widerAction.options.page;
// const page2: string | undefined
```

Note that the type of `page2` is `string | undefined` because it is possible that `action.options.page` is `undefined`.  This is the same end result as the `page` assignment above, with less type guard wrangling.

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-KFmIA1pgBHxnK1lCw8D73Y4Azy9rQDonhRBU+maK4aMkDPB3nAALxwZ3B4Cu5D5znclr0bv+3sGINDODMYmWdDIYC0TJJusG95orjGOAT4BT2y0Ny1uTwYtoRlIBmkqGWKDNgdITILhvtgBMl4PUY9Q5YI+Ac+Ft7eD+XElXddNxnNxXCAA)